# Could a reflective beam expander deteriorate the lateral symmetry of a beam collimated from a single-mode optical fiber?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, spectroscopy, microscopy

**Background:** I am currently concerned with getting a confocal time-correlated single-photon counting (TCSPC) setup ready for autocorrelation spectroscopy (fundamentally: fluorescence autocorrelation (FCS) and cross-correlation (FCCS) spectroscopy). The setup was initially assembled and well documented by someone else and is technically functional, evident by the ability to determine fluorescence lifetimes in the nanoseconds range (PicoQuant TCSPC electronics, picosecond-pulsed lasers with suitable drivers + oscillators); however, this person did not set-up the microscope for autocorrelation spectroscopy. I recently did several modifications to the detection pathway, switching from a fiber-based to a fiberless pathway from the confocal pinhole toward the avalanche photodiodes (APDs). The determination of fluorescence lifetimes (which might not be critically dependent on the shape of the confocal volume, as long as concentrations are low and the confocal volume is small enough) still appears to work well. However, the diffusion time of Rhodamine 6G (a fluorophore frequently used for confocal volume calibrations) through the confocal volume (as obtained from the autocorrelation curve by fitting a diffusion model) is several times too large, indicating that the confocal volume itself is rather large.

**Observations:** Eventually, I realized that there are likely several reasons for the observed long diffusion times and I shall consider them systematically. However, I also made the following observations which has led me to pose a question:

- Laser light is coupled into a single-mode fiber (PicoQuant), collimated with a suitable zoom fiber collimator (with variable collimation, set to infinity, Thorlabs) and subsequently expanded with a reflective 6-times beam expander (with spherical mirrors, Thorlabs) before overfilling the back-aperture of a 40-times water immersion objective. Whilst the laser profile looks perfectly symmetric after the zoom fiber collimator, it becomes somewhat ellipsoid after having passed the reflective beam expander (as judged by eye).
- Since the reflective beam expander is eventually attached to the back-port of a standard microscope (Olympus IX-83), the focal spot can be imaged through one of the oculars when focusing into e.g. a concentrated fluorophore solution. There, the focus appears (rather strongly) elongated in one axis rather than symmetric.

**Question:** Eventually, I am curious whether a 6-times reflective beam expander could distort the lateral profile of well-collimated light from a single-mode optical fiber to a degree that it caused strong distortions of the focal spot? My personal knowledge of optics is largely restricted to simple geometrical optics but I have come to realize that people rather use Keplarian or Galilean telescopes with lasers and hardly reflective expanders.

**Perhaps:** If someone was quite aware of typical reasons for too-large confocal volumes I would be glad for you suggestions!

Thank you!

---

**edit 0425**

*@José Andrade:* Thank you for suggesting astigmatism due to the reflective design of the beam expander as a potential source of "focal volume badness". This publication I found suggests that an astigmatic excitation beam can have severe effects on the shape of the focal volume:

- La Ruiz de Cruz, A. et al. Independent control of beam astigmatism and ellipticity using a SLM for fs-laser waveguide writing. *Opt. Express* **17,** 20853–20859 (2009).

Again, I find it hard to estimate whether astigmatism introduced by the reflective expander is of practical relevance to the shape of the confocal volume or whether this effect is rather homeopathic under the given conditions. However, since you sound confident with regard to the Galilean beam expander design I shall try to give it a go. To that effect I ought to establish a way to determine whether the collimated beam is truly astigmatic, following your suggestion with the camera and lens - and get a Gaussian beam expander with rotatable lenses (the current model I have available is integrated into a 30 mm cage system and the lenses are thus not rotatable)!

*@JB2:* Light from the single-mode fiber is collected via a fiber collimator with adjustable focal length and collimation (ZC618APC-A, Thorlabs): currently set to 18 mm focal length (for a maximum beam diameter (regarding objective back aperture overfilling)) and collimation to infinity, the collimated ray of light emerging from the collimator has about 3 mm diameter. The collimator is directly attached to the reflective beam expander. The input aperture of the reflective beam expander is easily large enough to accept the light from the zoom fiber collimator. That said, upon coupling-in a beam with a large input diameter, Thorlabs specifies that the wavefront error becomes quite large (approx. 2$\lambda$ P-W WE at 3 mm). However, I am not aware whether such wavefront error could lead to a noticeable degradation of the focal spot. Astigmatism due to the spherical mirrors within the reflective beam expander might also be problematic. I am currently trying to look at implications of (i) excitation light wavefront errors and (ii) astigmatism in more detail.

[image: https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=4089&pn=BE06R/M]

> Try putting a flat mirror on the entrance port of the Thorlabs device- your input beam should reflect off of that flat mirror on a retro path back to its source.

I shall think about how to implement this in practice.

Comment: I build concave-convex mirror telescopes (I refer to them as galilean, as they do not create a focus in between) all the time in my broadband laser beamlines because its possible to completely eliminate astigmatism with proper alignment. But the problem lies exactly on the exact alignment. To test this use a simple lens and a camera that you can translate through the caustic (the focus). Astigmatic beams will look like a line focus in one direction and later in the perpendicular direction. To get rid of this adjust the AOI on the telescope mirrors until you have a single round focus.

Comment: It is possible that the 6X telescope is causing your problems.  I would guess that ThorLabs can build these to specification, but they have to be used with properly aligned input beams.   You don't say what aperture the beams are going into the 6x expander- the Thor Labs spec for BE06R calls for a 0.5 mm input beam - If you exceed this, the aberrations may be more sensitive to alignment.   Try putting a flat mirror on the entrance port of the Thorlabs device- your input beam should reflect off of that flat mirror on a retro path back to its source.

Comment: @José Andrade: Thank you kindly for responding! I have addressed your comment in my initial post.

Comment: @JB2: Thank you kindly for responding! I have addressed your comment in my initial post.